# how to save/load database in a c# winform application?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, load, save

I've created an application (using c# winforms) in which I'm managing item sheets such books, music and movie dvds, games, etc. Those sheets contain basic information such title, synopsis, author, etc. There are even images (full-size + thumbnail).

So now I'm entering the stage of development where I need to save all the changes and load them again when I re-open the application. It's the first time I'm doing this kind of operation so I'm unsure of the best ways to do this.

So how do we save/load a database in a C# winform application? Are there best or faster methods than others?

Any link to tutorials would be greatly appreciated, I haven't found any valuable ones on my own, or the ones I've found dealt with Web applications.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) is the way to go.

I'd suggest to pay close attention to **CodeFirst** feature of EF because you have an application but don't have a DB yet. Here is [Tutorial: Code First with EF 4.1](http://codefirst.codeplex.com)

Answer (score 0):

entity framework is probably your easiest choice. here is a tutorial:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use "SQL Compact Edition" (I call it is Local SQL) with Windows Form application.
So you can load/save your database easily without connect to other DBMS.
http://www.microsoft.com/sql/editions/compact/default.mspx

Answer (score 0):

### Loading Database Data into a Winforms App

If you do not wish to use Entity Frameworks (for instance in a performance critical case) the direct use of   [ADO.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb9s9ks0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [System.Data.SqlClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t72t3k4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  is another way to go. This approach assumes that you are using [Microsoft SQL Server](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=119221):

The method can be called like this: `GetSqlData("Select * from myTable")`.

```
public static DataTable GetSqlData(string sql)
{
    // get Connectionstring from app.config 
    string connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YourConnection"];
    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (var command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = myConnection;
            command.CommandText = sql;
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);                                        
            dt.Load(reader);
        }
        return dt;
    }            
}// End of GetSqlData
```

#### Regarding the tutorials

Since the great website from microsoft called windowsclient.net (with lots of user input and official videos) is gone ([1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/23ebc4fc-3976-41cc-bcf9-2152dfed1446),[2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/d0c85c04-9c54-4328-a3a0-a5c13a4477d1/)) you can google for [beth massi forms over data video series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2007/08/01/forms-over-data-video-series-two-more-videos-released.aspx) or just [forms over data](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vbvideosdata/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=16) and you will find what is left from the windowsclient.net website.